# Userforms causing excel 2013 to crash

Tags: excel, crash, vba

I have the following issue:

I create a userform in excel 2013 and add for starters one text box to show the date and right underneath a combobox which is reflecting a data validation list.

As soon as i write the code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.tbDate = Date

'fill combobox
For Each cell In [cartridges]
    Me.cmbCartridges.AddItem cell
Next cell

End Sub
```

Can anyone help pretty please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should work. I am running Excel 2013 as well and just tested your code with no problems.

Two things to check.

## 1

Make sure that the defined name is spelled exactly the same way in the VBA code as it is in the Name Manger.

## 2

Make sure that the defined name does not evaluate to an error.

Comment: Super thanks buddy but i double check everything name wise no problem at all. As for the 2 point you made i didnt really get what do i have to check,,,, Thanks again

Comment: OK. Regarding item number 2, can you go to the worksheet and select a small range of cells, for example: Z10:Z15 (this could be any blank range) and then once that range is selected, enter: `=cartridges` and then confirm array-style with Control-Shift-Enter. Does it work or do you get errors?

Comment: OK. Here is a quicker way to add the list (no looping through the cells): `v = [cartridges]: cmbCartridges.List = v` By the way, can you accept the answer?